# How to Combine audio and Video in android

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I can getting audio from Camera microphone and I saved it .mp3 format to use below code,I am trying combine Video and Audio Data and playing them at same time,how can I do this?

```
   File ses = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/", "ses.mp3");
   String path2 = String.valueOf(ses);

  MediaRecorder recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path2);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
```

I can convert NV21 byte data to .h264 format and I played Video from getting Camera data

```
    private CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack callBack = new CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack() {

        @Override
        public void onDataBack(byte[] data, long length) {

            encode(data);
}
```

Encode Video Process

```
//Video format H264
private synchronized void encode(byte[] data) {
    ByteBuffer[]  inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[]  outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.capacity();
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data);
        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "outputBufferIndex-->" + outputBufferIndex);
    do {
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            System.out.println("buffer info-->" + bufferInfo.offset + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.size + "--" + bufferInfo.flags + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outBuffer.get(outData);
            try {
                if (bufferInfo.offset != 0) {
                    fos.write(outData, bufferInfo.offset, outData.length
                            - bufferInfo.offset);
                } else {
                    fos.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                }
                fos.flush();
                Log.i(TAG, "out data -- > " + outData.length);
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,
                        0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        }
    } while (outputBufferIndex >= 0);
}
```

Comment: do you just want to play audio and video both at runtime or do you want to combine them and save them as a video ?

Comment: I want to combine them and save them as video,Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes ill Answer in a few minutes. Please wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you can use a library called FFMPEG Android
It takes params as command lines and processed any video and audio. You may need to go through some documentation of FFMPEG android, I used this library to add water mark to a video splitting the video in frames and then adding water mark to it. It did really good Job, I also tested it to combine audio and It Helped.

Here is Code sample that I used.

```
 ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStart() {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure() {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        final String fileP = lipModel.filePath;

                                        String[] cmd = {"-i", lipModel.filePath, "-i", imagePath, "-preset", "ultrafast", "-filter_complex", "[1:v]scale="+width*0.21+":"+height*0.35+" [ovrl],[0:v][ovrl] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)", outputPath};
                                        try {
                                            // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
                                            ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onStart() {
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onProgress(String message) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: " + message);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(String message) {

                                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + message);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + message);

                                                    new AsyncDispatcher(new IAsync() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void IOnPreExecute() {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public Object IdoInBackGround(Object... params) {

                                                            File file = new File(lipModel.filePath);
                                                            if (file.exists()) {
                                                                file.delete();
                                                            }

                                                            lipModel.filePath = outputPath;
                                                            lipModel.contentUri = Uri.parse(new File(lipModel.filePath).toString()).toString();


                                                            lipSyncSerializedModel.lipSyncMap.put(lipModel.uniqueName, lipModel);
                                                            ObjectSerializer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).serialize(SerTag.LIP_HISTORy, lipSyncSerializedModel);


                                                            HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void run() {
                                                                    if (LipSyncFragment.iOnNewDataAddedRef != null) {
                                                                        LipSyncFragment.iOnNewDataAddedRef.newDataAdded();


//                        historyFragment.favModel = favModel;


                                                                    }
                                                                    LipsyncHistoryFragment lipHistory = new LipsyncHistoryFragment();

                                                                    File file = new File(fileP);
                                                                    if (file != null) {
                                                                        if(file.exists()){
                                                                            file.delete();
                                                                            Log.d(TAG, "run: Deleted the Orignal Video");
                                                                        }
                                                                    }

                                                                    new FragmentUtils(HomeActivity.this,
                                                                            lipHistory, R.id.fragContainer);
                                                                }
                                                            });


                                                            return null;
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void IOnPostExecute(Object result) {

                                                        }
                                                    });


                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onFinish() {
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                                            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
```

FFMPEG Documentation Link: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

FFMPEG Library: https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java

There is another Library that does the same

```
public class Mp4ParserAudioMuxer implements AudioMuxer {
@Override
public boolean mux(String videoFile, String audioFile, String outputFile) {
    Movie video;
    try {
        video = new MovieCreator().build(videoFile);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    Movie audio;
    try {
        audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);
    video.addTrack(audioTrack);

    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);

    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = 
        new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);

    try {
        out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
        byteBufferByteChannel.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

You can also try these But it will not be so easy,
You need to learn about these api's

1. [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) to extract data/track from file.
2. [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) if you want to encode/decode
3. [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to mux it into mp4 file

You can use all three of them together if you need to or individually.
You can find some example code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-5.1.1_r1/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts).

Comment: I am trying Mp4ParserAudioMuxer method but Where is the AudioMuxer library,it cannot in mp4ParserLibrary

Comment: I am getting this error in method Mp4Parser "java.lang.RuntimeException: I don't know how to deal with UInt64! long is not sufficient and I don't want to use BigInt"